# synonym for child-like [adult]

Tags: terminology

There is a specific term, and it keeps evading me, that refers to an adult who still embraces child-like wonder, curiosity, etc....

Not inferring a *child-like* or *infantile* adult, i.e. someone with a disorder.

I believe it begins with "N".  Anyone who may know, your input would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Childlike: does not necessarily suggest *disorder* of any kind: 

Like or befitting a child, as in innocence, trustfulness, or candor. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/childlike

Comment: ***Childlike*** is usually *positive*. The *negative* version is ***childish***.

Comment: Naive comes to mind - other synonyms are ingenuous, innocent

Comment: 'starry=eyed threw up the following 'nn's: nephelococcygeal adj, unworldly. cloud nine, non-realistic.

Comment: What did a thesaurus recommend (and can you tell us what wasn't good about those)?

Answer (score 2):

[Naive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/naive) is probably the term you are looking for:

> - Lacking worldly experience and understanding, especially:
> - Simple and guileless; artless: a child with a naive charm.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: Yup as commented already

Comment: @mplungjan - didn't see your comment, I was just writing mine, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**Jejune**

> Jejune [adjective]
>   Naive, simplistic, and superficial:    (Oxford)

Ludic

**Free spirit**

> “I like to be a free spirit. Some don't like that, but that's the way
>   I am.” ― Diana Princess of Wales

irresponsible

Uncommitted

Answer (score 0):

Immature, infantile, puerile, spontaneous, all these words come to mind when we talk about an adult who shows a child-like curiosity.

> spontaneous (adj)
>
> - "done or said in a natural and often sudden way and without a lot of thought or planning"
> - "doing things that have not been planned but that seem enjoyable and worth doing at a particular time"  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spontaneous)

Answer (score 0):

Neoteny - i was just trying to remember it and the "N" in the above comment zapped it right back into my brain.

Comment: This would be better if you included a dictionary definition too.

Comment: _Neoteny_ is a great word, but it seems to be used primarily in physiological accounts of juvenile (versus adult) characteristics, rather than in a figurative sense for childlike behavior or naivete. I second KillingTime's recommendation that you provide a linked dictionary definition of _neoteny_ in support of your suggestion—and will be happy to upvote your answer if you do so. You'll find one such definition [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neoteny), although—again—it doesn't seem entirely applicable to the situation that the original poster asks about.